# pros and cons of html/php file loading within a div with jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello i made this function to change a my content div depending on the selected menu item.
Is loading html/php files into a div a good idea? what are the cons and pros of this method?

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list nav-stacked">             
    <li id="meniu-item-1><a href="#">Apie mus</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#meniu-item-1").click(function(){
            $("#changing-div").load('content.php');
        });
    });
```

Comment: if you are doing something simple, this is probably unnecessary. if you are doing something complex, I would suggest to use a framework like backbone to help you do this and prevent you from re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: To decide if this is a *"good idea"* (which is arguably off topic) and generate pros and cons, we need more context. What kind of content is it? does it need to be search indexable? is there another way to obtain the data without ajax for the search engines if needed? what did you intend to gain from doing it this way rather than reloading the page? how much content are you changing? does the additional content need it's own javascript?

Comment: it's for my admin panel so SEO is not needed :) i have a 2 div admin panel 1/3 Left meniu and 2/3 right the part that i want to be changing when i press menu item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main cons are:

- Accessibility, Screen Readers can't get to the rest of the data nor tell where the link (if it is still a link at all)
- Search Engines can't reach the page, as such all content can not be indexed

A work around include a static method as without javascript that link will not work and no data will be found. you can do this with progressive enhancement:

```
<a href="Page1.php">Page1</a>
<a href="Page2.php">Page2</a>

<div id="#changing-div"></div>
```

your js becomes

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
   $("#changing-div").load($(this).attr('href'));
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Note if the Page1.php url returns the whole page you can grab only part of the content by using

```
$("#changing-div").load($(this).attr('href')+' #justContent);
```

Where `#justContent` is a wrapper around the content you wanted.

This also means that SEO is unaffected as your page is still reachable by search engines

Comment: I have this html how do i fit your js to this ? :) 

    <ul class="nav nav-list nav-stacked">     
          <li ><a href="apie-mus-admin.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign desine10"></span>Apie mus</a></li>
        </ul>

Comment: @Jugernaut could you update your question with this code please?, but from what i can tell your href for all <a> tags should go be filled with a page that has the content that the load would have returned (but as a page with all its template gloriness) :)

Comment: @Jugernaut ok thats simple, where there is `href="#"` put the url you'll want to pull data from

Comment: I figured that out :) but it doesn't load in that div it just loads the file :)

Comment: @Jugernaut make sure to have `e.preventDefault();` present to stop normal execution

Comment: yeah it works :) i failed a bit. Loaded the jquery library after that code not before :) i have a few links that don't have to use this jquery code how do i make them act normal ?

Comment: @Jugernaut change where it says "a" to just be a class and put the class where you need the behavoir

Comment: silly me :)) sorry for the dumb questions i'm kinda new to coding :)

Answer (score 1):

I made something similar at first on my website. I then realize it kind of killed my "search engine compatibility". Personnaly, I woul recommend you put all in div at start and change the visibility upon clicks, if it doesn't ask to much on your customers networks.